# Preventing a column from resizing according to the longest width in android

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am writing code for a calendar view in my app. I have a `TableLayout` with 8 `TableRow`s:

- 6 for the days in the current, previous, and next months.
- 1 for the list of days (Sun, Mon, Tue, etc.)
- 1 for the current month name (January, February, etc.) and 2 buttons: next month and previous month.

It looks roughly like this:

```
________________________________________________
|  <  | December |  >  |                       |
| Sun | Mon      | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
| 29  | 30       | 31  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | x6
________________________________________________
```

The thing is that a whole column resizes based on the cell with the longest width as seen in the sketch above. This may be the expected behavior for a table layout, but, is there a way to avoid it using any of the `TableLayout`'s attributes or methods? or should I just use a different layout for the first row?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `android:stretchColumns=2` to stretch secondcolumn and `android:layout_span` to adjust other columns.